# A Love letter with No Name

Tags: riddle, wordplay

A certain young gentleman received a confusing and cryptic letter, which he assumes is a love letter. But alas, the letter has no name on it. The letter is as reads below:

> Hey, baby, won't you look my way, I could be your new addiction. Well, maybe not me, seeing as I didn't write that. The question is, who did?
>
> I apologize if I'm not making much sense, because there is an annoying insect in my room. It sounds like haemophilia, but it shares it's roots with anthropology. I have Nikolai to blame for that. Look, out, Gansey!!
>
> I'll have to go kill it now, because, honey, there ain't no rest for the wicked. (I didn't write that line either, by the way.)
>
> I'm also craving some homeomorphic toroidal polyhedrons, but I'd rather share them with you rather then eat them alone. I suppose I could write it all down in one letter.
>
> I'd rather tell you how I'm feeling, boy, and how I'm doing things my way. If I'd got my piano, then I'd know things were okay. (Is there a limit to the amount of allusions you can make in one letter? Take my first two letters, I suppose, and you'd get your answer,)
>
> And in my last letter... well, Fabian and Gideon can tell you, it's the first letter of their last of names.
>
> It's elementary, my dear, and if you can't figure this out, then I'd have to infer that you aren't really worth the unrequited crush.
>
> If you figure out the name I've been trying to tell you, then you'll know who I am, because I am his daughter.
>
> Solve it by the 26th, baby, we ride then at midnight. Bring the potatoes.
>
> Yours Truly,
>
> Me

What is the name of the author of the letter?

Comment: Some crazy love letter you got there

Comment: "we ride then at midnight. Bring the potatoes." this line alone makes the lover amazing ;D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think I have most of it

The clues are:

1.

> Lyrics from a song by **Ne**on Trees

2.

> **B**umblebee is the insect. It's also a song by Nikolai Rimsky-Korsakov. Gansey is apparently a character from a book series called The Raven Cycle and he is allergic to bees and wasps.

3.

> A song by **Ca**ge the Elephant

4.

> It's an **O** shape

5.

> Song by **Ar**iana Grande

6.

> Last name of Fabian and Gideon **P**rewett (Thanks @AZGreenTea!)

All the clues are:

> Elements from the periodic table of elements. 1-Neon 2-Boron 3-Calcium 4-Oxygen 5-Argon 6-Phosphorus

Then

> Their atomic  numbers are 10, 5, 20, 8, 18, and 15 which can be translated to their corresponding letter in the alphabet (a=1, b=2, etc.) which comes out to JETHRO. There aren't any anagrams of Jethro, so is the answer Jethro's Daughter? Maybe Gael Anderson, daughter of Ian Anderson front man of the band Jethro Tull?

EDIT:

> The last line about the potatoes seems to be a Tumblr meme, not sure if it's a clue or not.

EDIT 2:

> @AZGreenTea pointed out that it might be Zipporah, daughter of Reuel and Jethro and wife of Moses. Moses isn't going to be happy if he hears about this!

Comment: Ah atomic numbers! I should have known. Anyhow googling <name>'s daughter gives a biblical answer. That might be it?

Comment: Ooh that might be it, I'll add it to the answer!

Comment: Ding ding ding! Nice job. I apologize for the whole things about the band, I didn't know there was one with the same name. Edit two is correct...

Comment: Just a comment on the "daughter of Reuel and Jethro" part in the second edit, I'm almost positive that Reuel and Jethro are the same person, whereas your edit makes it sound like they're two different people.

Answer (score 3):

An incomplete attempt at the clues:

1. Hey, baby, won't you look my way, I could be your new addiction.

> These are lyrics from Everybody Talks by **Neon Trees**.

2. I apologize if I'm not making much sense, because there is an annoying insect in my room. It sounds like haemophilia, but it shares it's roots with anthropology. I have Nikolai to blame for that. Look, out, Gansey!!

> Not too sure about this, but the annoying insect could refer to the **Bee**, from The Flight of the Bumblebee by Nikolai Rimsky-Korsakov. Don't know how haemophilia, anthropology and Gansey fit into this though.

3. there ain't no rest for the wicked.

> This is a song by **Cage The Elephant**

4. homeomorphic toroidal polyhedrons

> These are **Donut** shapes. With the new edit, I'm inclined to think the letter is O.

5. I'd rather tell you how I'm feeling, boy, and how I'm doing things my way. If I'd got my piano, then I'd know things were okay.

> This is a song lyric from Piano by **Ariana Grande**

6. Fabian and Gideon can tell you

> Fabian and Gideon **Prewett** are from the Harry Potter universe.

This is where I'm stumped.

With @AJL's comment, I do notice that there are a lot of elements involved here.

> 1. **NE**on, 2. **B**oron or **Be**ryllium, 3.??? 4.**O**xygen? 5.**Ar**gon, 6.**P**hosphorus

Still have no idea what 3 is on about, nor how these elements come into play.
Feel free to use my answers if you can solve it, anyone!

Comment: Assuming you got #2 and #4 wrong, but the rest correct (N?C?ARP), the most likely anagram would be CYPRIAN. "The Cyprian" can refer to Aphrodite, but "the name" is apparently supposed to be male since the letter says "I am *his* daughter."

Comment: in #1, the question is 'who did?'. So maybe the answer of #1 is 'Everybody talks' and then the letter is E

Comment: Maybe elements have something to do with it?

Comment: You guys are got half... maybe AJL is on the right track? (I mean, thanks for just reading my "riddle")

Comment: *If* #4 is wrong, there is another foodstuff that shares that shape. #3 is probably right, but it *is* an extremely common phrase that predates the song significantly.

Comment: Maybe you're closer to the truth when referring to the shape rather than the food?